# Как в Drupal 8 увеличить максимум вводимых тегов?

Tags: php, drupal

Есть у меня поле для тегов у контента, тип автодополнение, теги вводятся через запятую

Когда при создание контента я в это поле копирую большой список тегов, то он обрезается, и ничего больше в этом поле написать нельзя.

Можно как-то увеличить максимальную длину этого поля?

"Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему" - Проблема в том что я не могу ввести столько тегов сколько хочу, где то есть ограничение.

"как её воспроизвести" - Добавьте поле к контенту. 
тип 'taxonomy term'.
Допустимое количество значений 'неограничено'.
Тип ссылки 'default'.
Включите "Создать связанные сущности если они еще не существуют". 
Выберите словарь. 
Сохраните

В "Управление отображением формы" для созданного поля выбрать "Автодополнение в стиле тегов" чтоб теги можно было вводить через запятую в одно поле.

Попробуйте создать контент и в созданное поле вводить теги, или скопировать их туда, там есть ограничение, 1024 символов. Достигнув ограничения написать в то поле больше ничего нельзя

"что вы хотите получить в результате" - Хочу чтоб можно было ввести больше тегов

**Обновление**- Поиском текста по файлам нашел это ограничение, в файле "core\lib\Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\EntityReferenceAutocompleteWidget.php" надо изменить

```
**'#maxlength' => 1024,**
```

Тут появляться другой вопрос, как изменить эту опцию правильно? не раз в инструкциях всяких попадалось что в drupal лучше не менять ничего в папке core.

Comment: "Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода." Отредактировал